# LibreOffice fails to start

Tags: kde, libreoffice, 23.10

I'm on Ubuntu 23.10. I installed LibreOffice without errors.

However, when I try to start it, it doesn't. I've used LibreOffice on other Linux systems, CentOS and Rocky, without issues.

How do I fix this?

Comment: "when I try to start, it doesn't" is a very poor problem. statement, and contains no actionable information. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: ls -l /var/crash/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I installed LibreOffice via apt when I first installed Ubuntu 22.04. On the advice of others here. I reinstallede LibreOffice using apt and  it still fails.

When called via the command line, I get this error (don't see it if using KDE gui.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::container::NoSuchElementException'

Comment: More into. Tried reinstalling libreoffice using apt and last stable version from snap. Libreoffice still failed, Purged libreoffice and reinstalled using apt. Failed. In all cases, I got this error message when using the terminal.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::container::NoSuchElementException'

Comment: @MW please use the [edit] button to add all this information into your question

Comment: Have you tried temporarily moving or renaming your `~/.config/libreoffice` directory?

Comment: Can you start it in safe mode with running `libreoffice --safe-mode` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall libreoffice
open terminal ctl + alt + t

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Comment: Did so and LibreOffice still hails to start. I get a splash screen and nothing else. It appears to halt. I have to use cntl-C to exit.

BTW, reinstalling LibreOffice does NOT correct the issue.

Comment: Do you have DIscover software manager on your system? Try uninstalling LibreOffice using your terminal... sudo apt-get remove –purge libreoffice   and then try reinstalling it using Discover, it might be wanting to use a specific LibreOffice package for your system.

Comment: The community bot, waltinator and steeldriver community members have been encouraging you to edit your question and add more info to the body of the original question. If you really need Libreoffice that will be your best bet to finding a solution. Go to the links that waltinator gave at the top of the posts, to learn about better formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Hello LibreOffice I have encountered this problem
Just reinstall LibreOffice
Method 1:
Visit this pagehttps://snapcraft.io/install/libreoffice/ubuntu
Method 2: Open terminal Ctrl + Alt + T Enter:
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
`Sudo APT-GET reinstall LibreOffice`
good luck

Comment: I get a 404 error on the snapcraft link.

Comment: @MW try agian thís link https://snapcraft.io/install/libreoffice/ubuntu